# Compare the file names to create the folders they will be moved to

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to create folders according their filenames and move files in their respective folders.
For example, I have these files

```
daily planet today.pdf
daily planet tomorrow.pdf
the bridge fall.pdf
the bridge arise.pdf
```

I have no folders
I test this script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do (
  mkdir %%I
  if exist "%%I*.cbr" move /Y "%%I*.cbr" "%%I\"
)
endlocal
```

but it doesn't create `daily planet` and `the bridge` folders. I expect this situation but it fails (nothing happens)

```
daily planet
     |
     +-- daily planet today.pdf
     +-- daily planet tomorrow.pdf


the bridge
     |
     +-- the bridge fall.pdf
     +-- the bridge arise.pdf
```

Comment: To begin with, `/AD` will enumerate directories, and you wanted to enumerate PDF files. Change that to `/A-D`, which means those without a Directory Attribute. Then before you can Make the Directory, you'll need to incorporate some code which determines from the file names returned as `%%I`, the substring you wish to extract from it for your directory names.

Comment: Are folder names _always_ formed by 2 adjacent words? If not (if there are more or less than 3 words in the file name), how many words will form the folder name?

Comment: At first, `mkdir %%I` should be `mkdir "%%I"`. Then you have to exactly specify how to derive the names of the new directories from the file names (do they consist of the first two space-separated words, or do they consist of the last-but-one space-separated words, or is there any other logic behind it?)…

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @greg-449 Question is not answered -->> I want to delete it, please to do it otherwise I contact Moderators

Comment: You can't delete it, it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: @user332153 1), the license is not a trick and they're not my rules.  2)  You have been told by 2 people now not to and why you shouldn't, vandalize your posts.  3), *why* does the question absolutely have to be deleted?  You've gotten 2 downvotes.  *Two*.  If that's why you want it gone, that's not reason enough for repeated vandalism, insults, and general behavior that will very likely get you suspended.

Answer (score 1):

This method assumes that the folder name consist of the last-but-one space-separated words from the file name:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in (*.pdf) do (

   set "file=%%I"
   for %%J in ("!file: =\!") do set "folder=!file: %%~nxJ=!"

   mkdir "!folder!" 2>NUL
   move /Y "!file!" "!folder!"
   echo "!file!" moved to "!folder!"

)
```

For example:

```
"the bridge fall.pdf" moved to "the bridge"
"the bridge arise.pdf" moved to "the bridge"
"bridge fall.pdf" moved to "bridge"
"bridge arise.pdf" moved to "bridge"
"the last bridge fall.pdf" moved to "the last bridge"
"the last bridge arise.pdf" moved to "the last bridge"
```